# when should I use open/read/write and fopen/fread/write

Tags: c, linux, io

open/read/write are low-level I/O functions, and if speed is of my first concern, how to choose between open/read/write and fopen/fread/fwrite?

Comment: Consider that the stdio functions call the underlying OS functions to do their work... if you think you can write code that works better than the C standard library, feel free to do so.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill any tips for implementing my own I/O functions, if I want to make it faster than fopen/fread/fwrite?

Comment: That totally depends on the file access patterns of your application. If you're reading sequentially, you'll want a big buffer. If you're seeking around a lot, you might want to use asynchronous I/O. If you want another really fast alternative, consider memory mapped files.

Comment: @greg Hewgill Thank you, I think I am gonna do a benchmarking first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The higher level functions provide you with ease of usage also, functions like `fopen()` provides you with in-built I/O buffering unlike `open()`. The I/O buffering ensures `fopen()` is much faster than `open()`.

Apart from the above distinction If you have just file descriptor, you should use read, write etc, While If you have a `FILE *`, you should use functions like `fread`, `fwrite` etc.

Comment: but, which is faster under different conditions?

Comment: @MickeyShine: Perhaps you should create a benchmark to find out. If performance is a concern for you, you're going to *need* those benchmarking tools later.

Comment: @MickeyShine: You should do what Greg suggested, to answer your query, Usually, if you are doing lot of seek operations I/O buffering is performance goes down, while if you are reading or writing to a file sequentially the I/O buffering helps performance.

Comment: @Als  thank you for your answer, you mean direct I/O functions (open/read/write) are better for random（a lot of seek）operations, and buffered I/O (fopen/read/write) are better for sequential operations, right?